# Vue App API Form works on localhost but not once deployed

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, vue.js, axios

My code works fine on my local server, but once I deployed to my website, I cannot get the data to display. I keep getting a "Form submission cancelled because form is not connected". Axios is actually putting the data into my database, just it will not display on my interface. When I console.log(app.Users) it returns undefined. Thank you

```js
<script>
      var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
          errorMsg: "",
          successMsg: "",
          showAddModal: false,
          showEditModal: false,
          showDeleteModal: false,
          users: [],
          newUser: { name: "", email: "", phone: "" },
          currentUser: {},
        },
        mounted: function () {
          this.getAllUsers();
        },
        methods: {
          getAllUsers() {
            axios
              .get(
                "http://jakewoodruff.com/Projects/crud-vue-php/process.php?action=read"
              )
              .then(function (response) {
                if (response.data.error) {
                  app.errorMsg = response.data.message;
                } else {
                  app.users = response.data.users;
                  console.log(app.users);
                }
              });
          },
          addUser() {
            var formData = app.toFormData(app.newUser);
            axios
              .post(
                "http://jakewoodruff.com/Projects/crud-vue-php/process.php?action=create",
                formData
              )
              .then(function (response) {
                app.newUser = { name: "", email: "", phone: "" };
                if (response.data.error) {
                  app.errorMsg = response.data.message;
                } else {
                  app.successMsg = response.data.message;
                  app.getAllUsers();
                }
              });
          }
```

Comment: you have `Connected Successfully` being outputted in your json response

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes I am connected successfully to database, my form is successfully adding the info to the database, it is just not successfully adding to my page. I am getting a "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"

Comment: Try changing all instances of `app` to `this` and see if that helps. I am wondering if the Temporal Dead Zone is affecting your use of `app` in production.

Comment: @Tony OP would also need to move to arrow functions

Comment: @JakeWoodruff what Lawrence is saying is that having `Connected Successfully` in your output invalidates the JSON response. Axios will not be able to parse the response properly

Comment: @PhilYes just removing the Connected Successfully echo fixed my error Thank you all so much! I didn't quite understand what he meant, thanks for clarifying